# Como criar loop para emitir um evento em socket.io?

Tags: node.js, loop, socket, socket.io

Estou com um problema de arquitetura.

Tenho um código utilizando [socket.io](http://socket.io/) em [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/):

```js
socket.on('images',function (aData){
    ...
    socket.sockets.emit('show', JSON.stringify({imagens : json}))
});
```

Estou a tentar fazer um broadcast tempo em tempo no evento "show", porém os sockets conecatados não podem ficar enviando o evento images toda hora.

Um *loop* no próprio backend poderia resolver a questão, mas preciso de um gatilho para o evento `images` que não seja os sockets conetados.

Algum solução ou alternativa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez o [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> te ajude, através do uso de uma função anónima:

```js
var show = setInterval(function() {
    socket.sockets.emit('show', JSON.stringify({imagens : json}))
}, 10000);
```

O segundo argumento diz respeito ao tempo em milissegundos que a função `setInterval()` deverá esperar entre cada chamada.